# is XOR-hash difference-unpredictable

Tags: hash, pseudo-random-function, xor

Let $F$ be a PRF.

The $XOR\text{-hash}$ is defined as:

```
XOR-hash(k, m):    //m=(a₀, a₁, ..., aᵥ)
    t = 0ⁿ
    for each aᵢ ∈ m:
        t = t ⊕ F(k, aᵢ)
    return t
```

Suppose an attacker $\mathcal{A}$ can send 3-uples $(m_0, m_1, \delta)$.

A function $f$ will be difference-unpredictable if $\mathcal{A}$ cannot guess a 3-uple such that $f(k,m_0) - f(k,m_1) = \delta \;$ with more than negligible chance.

How can I show that $XOR\text{-hash}$ is difference-unpredictable?

---

I think the argument relies on the fact that $\oplus$ keep all the bits pseudo-random, so that the difference $d$ will look like a subtraction of two random results, hence the probability of some bit of $d$ match some bit of $\delta$ will be $\small\sim$$0.5$ and the probability of $d = \delta$ would be negligible.

Comment: I assume $m_0$ and $m_1$ must be distinct.  $(0 \mathbin\Vert 1, 1 \mathbin\Vert 0, 0)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot prove that this is difference unpredictable since it is not. Take $\delta=0$ and set $m_0=(a_0,a_1)$ and $m_1=(a_1,a_0)$.

Comment: That's true... I was trying to prove it was unpredictable and I forgot to think about a counter-example to show that it could not be proved.